# Configuring code coverage with VSTest@2 task in Azure DevOps "Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, vstest

I am trying to configure the VSTest@2 task in an Azure DevOps build pipeline to provide a code coverage metric.

When the pipeline runs, the logs for the task show this error (but the tests themselves run and pass):

```
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.
Data collection : Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'
```

The target framework is net472 and the unit tests are implemented with NUnit and referencing NUnit 3.13.2 and NUnit3TestAdapter 4.1.0.

YAML task:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
```

What is missing to enable code coverage for the VSTest@2 task? Does a data collector need to be configured and how can that be achieved?

Comment: May I ask why you're using dotnet vstest vs dotnet test?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.